# Not able to click on first element in the table through Java selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have to click on first link in the table.
Not able to click the link, it's id and xpath is changing when a new record is created as follows :

```
Action  Exception Number                        
Edit | Del  EX-0000529

Edit | Del  EX-0000528

Edit | Del  EX-0000527

Edit | Del  EX-0000526

Edit | Del  EX-0000525
```

HTML is as follows :

```
 <td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-NAME " tabindex="0" 
 style="width:251px;">
 <div id="a3h290000001fC6_NAME" class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-NAME">
 <a href="/a3h290000001fC6">
 <span>EX-0000529</span>
 </a>
 </div>
 </td>
 <td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-NAME " tabindex="0" 
  style="width:251px;">
  <div id="a3h290000001f9v_NAME" class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-
  NAME">
  <a href="/a3h290000001f9v">
  <span>EX-0000528</span>
  </a>
  </div>
  </td>
```

Comment: Please clarify your description above the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

The provided html shows the table element you want to click is having a link. So First get all the links and then you can click on your desired link by index.

below is the sample code yo can workwith.

```
java.util.List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println(links.size());
for (WebElement elem : links)
{
    elem.click();
}
```

If you just want to click on the first link then just use below line instead of for loop.

```
links.get(0).click();
```

Comment: And if OP wants to click only first element, instead of using `for` loop, he can just use `links.get(0).click();` :)

Answer (score 0):

To click on first link in the table i.e. **`EX-0000529`** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-NAME']//following::span[1]")).click();
```